# Redirect doesn't work after registering a new user to the db (express, mongoose, react)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm having trouble with this code, the new user is registered to the db just fine but just hangs after clicking the submit button. Would like to redirect to the login page. What am I missing?

```js
app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
  var body = req.body,
             username = body.username,
             password = body.password;
  User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, document) {
    if (err) { res.status(500).send('Error ocurred') }
    else {
      if (document) {
        { res.status(500).send('Username already exists.') }
      } else {
        User.register(new User({ username: req.body.username }), req.body.password, function(err, user) {
          if(err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
          return res.render('/login');
        })
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Is the POST request a form post from the browser or is it sent by Javascript via an Ajax call?  If it's a form post, you can do `res.redirect('someURL')`.  If it's an Ajax call, then your own Javascript will have to get the response from the POST and then do something useful (like redirect).  The browser doesn't pay any attention to an Ajax response itself.  You have to do that with your own client-side Javascript.

Comment: Thanks! Why does res.redirect work but res.render not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm inferring from your comments that this must be a form post that is creating this request.  If that's the case, then you can use

```
res.redirect('/login')
```

to tell the browser to load the /login URL when the POST is done.  The browser will then request the `/login` URL and your Express server will then serve that page back to the browser and the URL bar in the browser will show the redirected URL `http://somedomain.com/login` which is probably what you want.

As for `res.render()`, it expects a filename in your local file system, not a URL so I'm guessing that `/login` is not a valid filename that points to an HTML template for it to render which is why it doesn't work.